# Ajax request 'onError' handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is one feature on my site: delete without page refresh. The user just presses 'delete' and the browser will send Ajax-request. It will load 'delete' script with id parameter.

All work well. But it is not very good because of referential integrity of the database. For example, It is possible to delete street, where some people are living.

I want to upgrade my script. I want to add a check to delete script and don't let delete data if some 'people' are connected to 'street' table.

jQuery handler of button click:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteStreet', function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var hideMe = $(this).parent().parent();
    var dataString = 'id=' + id;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete street? It is possible some people living there!"))
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/index.pl?mode=streets&action=delete",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(e)
            {
                hideMe.hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

It will call script anyway and now will delete data anyway. I can add some checks to delete script now and it wouldn't delete, but jquery script would work anyway and will hide table row anyway (because request was send ok, without 404, etc)

1) Is it possible to see delete script result and hide or not hide row depending on it? For example, it will return true or false, js script will catch it and show message about deleting or not deleting of data depending on it.

2) This problem caused by structure of my site. There are some switches on `index.pl` and load appropriate scripts loading depending on query (`mode=street` then load `street.pl`, `mode=user` then load `users.pl` etc). So it will show all data loaded before `delete.pl` script and it will be impossible to check script returned true or false.

Any help? :) Thank you!

P.S.: I am very sorry for my awful english.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the result of your ajax call in the first parameter of the success callback. ex:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/index.pl?mode=streets&action=delete",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(e)
        {
            if(e === '1'){
               hideMe.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

try to log your result in the console for tests: `console.log(e)`.
For deleting data you should use a POST request ( or DELETE but not supported by all browsers).

I dont know how your datas (streets) looks like  but an other way could it be to return all your existing streets in a json object on the delete request result. And refresh all lines.

Comment: For deleting data you should use a POST request. Why? So end-user wouldn't just type `/users/delete/#id` and delete user? Yes, its ok, I just thought about it too.

Comment: Ok. E contain html of result. But it has tags `<html>....`. Look my 2nd problem. Also, can you explain when exactly e will become available?

Comment: You must call an other file in your ajax request, not the index. What looks like your delete function? what langage do you have server side? You should put your detele function in a other file.

Comment: Yes. It is possible, I know about it, but it isn't preferably. Any other methods? Delete is just sql statement 
Request with substituted id from get

Comment: Ok. For example. If I move data delete to other script, how check in jQuery will look like?
Is it OK to use this at all? I mean delete in other file?

Comment: Ah! Example is in your answer, I forget about it. But question is open: any others methods? Don't want to move code to separate file.

Comment: ok just realized you use Perl, not used to it. You dont need a other file, but you have to control what you return. if its a html with the list of your streets for example, you can refresh the tag containing your streets like this:`hideMe.html(e)`

Comment: Nope. I am hiding `hideMe` by `hideMe.hide()` at the moment. I need to call this function if html will contation true or false, for example. I can't do this, because `e` (it content requested page html) content is very complex (<html><body> many other html tags etc). How exactly I can control what it return?